# How to override customer AccountController in magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, module, customer, overrides, controllers

I was used below code but not work in-effect **it removes my login and registration link from the top links**.

**Config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mage_Customer>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mage_Customer>
  </modules>
   <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                    <mage_customer before="Mage_Customer">mage_customer</mage_customer>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mage_customer>
                    <file>customer.xml</file>
                </mage_customer>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <customer>
        <class>Mage_Customer_Helper</class>
      </customer>
    </helpers>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <customer>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>Mage_Customer</module>
          <frontName>admin_customer</frontName>
        </args>
      </customer>
    </routers>
  </admin>
</config>
```

**AccountController.php**

```
require_once "Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php";  
class Mage_Customer_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController{

}
```

**Modules/Mage_Customer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mage_Customer>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mage_Customer>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you change your module name

Because this name is conflict with magento core **Mage_Customer** module.

In below code you have defiended

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mage_Customer>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mage_Customer>
  </modules>
</config>
```

It will find all files related to customer module in local pool instead of core pool so it won't work.So change your module name is better option.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following code from your `config.xml`, it should bring your top links back:

```
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <mage_customer>
                <file>customer.xml</file>
            </mage_customer>
        </updates>
    </layout>
```

Comment: Not working.....